# Rails normalize before find_or_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model with an address field that needs to be unique:

```
class AddressMeta < AR::Base
  def normalize
    # normalize and store full_address
  end

  validates_uniqueness_of :full_address

  after_validation :normalize
end
```

I am passing addresses through a geocoding API to ensure that they are valid and normalized before storing.  The trouble I'm running into is that I also want addresses to be unique, so there's only a single record per unique address string.  Take the following addresses:

```
101 E 1st St #101, Austin, TX
101 E 1st Street Suite 101, Austin, TX
```

These two are obviously the same address, but I can't find the second in the database unless it is first normalized to match the first.  So if the first one exists and I run a `find_or_create_by(full_address: address)` call on the second, I end up missing with the search and creating a new object, and this results in a collision.

So - my question.  In Rails/AR, how can I normalize the input to the find_or_create_by method prior to performing the search?  Or is there a better way to handle the case that I have a collision on a unique field after normalizing a field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to determine without the full context of the code, however one solution is to change the normalize execution to occur **before** validation and not after:

```
class AddressMeta < AR::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :full_address

  before_validation do
    full_address = normalize_address(full_address)
  end

  private
  def normalize_address(address_string)
    # Code to convert address with API
    # Returns normalized address string
  end
end
```

That way the uniqueness validator should work. Also, a nice little refactor would be to extract the address normalization logic out into its own class:

```
# lib/address_converter.rb
class AddressConverter
  class << self
    def normalize(raw_address)
      # Logic and API Code
      # Returns normalized string
    end
  end
end

# app/models/address_meta.rb
require 'address_converter'

class AddressMeta < AR::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :full_address

  before_validation do
    full_address = AddressConverter::normalize(full_address)
  end
end
```

Comment: Great suggestions.  I ended up creating a new static method `normalized_find_or_create` that geocodes before searching and then creates a new object if it can't find one.  +1 for pulling logic out into its own class - I did that too.